# Open source applications for resizing drive partitions

Tags: partition

I am looking for open source applications that will allow resizing hard drive partitions. I have used partition magic in the past but am looking for open source free applications that can handle this task.

Comment: Related on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/39051/moving-space-from-d-to-c-server-2008

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've used [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) in the past with success, it's a linux boot disk designed for partitoning.  I should have mentioned that despite being a linux disk, it works for sorting out windows partitions too.  I split my laptop up to install the windows 7 beta using this.

Comment: Cannot agree more

Comment: GParted is nice and easy, and it is included in Live DVDs such as Ubuntu and Knoppix.